# increase index in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I try to make shortcode plugin which display number of my shortcodes.

```
<?php
$numberOfShortcodes = 0;

function ppndr_shortcode( $atts ){
    $numberOfShortcodes++;
    return $numberOfShortcodes; 
}

add_shortcode( 'countdown', 'ppndr_shortcode' );

?>
```

When i add two shortcodes it display "11". How to increase numberOfShortcodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `global` keyword:

```
<?php
$numberOfShortcodes = 0;

function ppndr_shortcode( $atts ){
    global $numberOfShortcodes;
    $numberOfShortcodes++;
    return $numberOfShortcodes; 
}

add_shortcode( 'countdown', 'ppndr_shortcode' );

?>
```

Why? You are trying to get value of global variable `$numberOfShortcodes`, but server thinks you want the local (from function scope), which is not set, so creates new one. If you use global, php will know, you mean the global variable and will use it.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '++' (T_INC), expecting ',' or ';'